# How to view .img file in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, geospatial, raster, gdal

I am working on a project which includes images which are in (.img) formats.
These images are easily open in Erdas or Qgis but I need to view them via python scripts. Is it possible to view image with the help of gdal? If yes, How?

Comment: Without context, ```.img``` is just a file-suffix which does not guarantee anything about the content. Find out what exact codec you are trying to decode and then the search for some python-decoder might be more easy.

Comment: Basically, these images are Erdas imagine .img file which stores raster data.

Comment: Check out my answer, but if that does not suffice you might have better luck over at the GIS Stack Exchange site: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think the first trick is to convert the Erdas Imagine files into a GeoTIFF. Check out this question over at the GIS Stack Exchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103827/convert-from-img-to-geotiff?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

After you have the file in GeoTIFF format you can view the image in Python a couple different ways. I like the [rasterio library](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html).

Viewing the image is pretty simple.

`import rasterio
 from rasterio.plot import show
 src = rasterio.open('your_raster_image.tif')
 show(src)`

Comment: Thank you, but when i convert .img file to tiff with the help of gdal, it produces invalid image. and btw I got the solution. With the help of gdal we can read bands, then band can be read as array. since the result is an array, it can be cast with astype and then by cv2 , we can view our band.

Comment: Great, glad you found a solution. Consider writing a brief answer and submitting the answer to your own question for others to see!